# Edit a dropdown list for a foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table named **marks** with 2 fields `id`, `name_mark`. Then, I have another table named **series** with 3 fields `id`, `name`, `fk_mark`.

My goal is to create an edit system. My first problem is in the dropdown list of my **foreign key (fk_mark)**, I always have the same item in each line.

[image]

Here is my **SerieController**

```
public function edit($id)
{
  $series = Serie::find($id);
  $marks = Mark::find($id);
  return view('admin.series.edit', compact('marks', 'series'));
}
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string',
    'fk_mark' => 'required'
  ]);
  $series = Serie::find($id);
  $series->name = $request->get('name');
  $series->fk_mark = $request->get('fk_mark');
  $series->save();
  return redirect()->route('series.index')
                   ->with('success', 'updated successfully');
}
```

In my **series.edit.blade** I have this

```
<form class="panel-body" action="{{route('series.update',$marks->id)}}" method="POST">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
  @csrf
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="form-group-input-1">Nom</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$series->nom}}">
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="company-content">Select Mark</label>
    <select name="fk_mark" id="" class="form-control">
      @foreach($marks as $mark)
        <option value="{{$marks->id}}">
          {{$marks->name_mark}}
        </option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your problem is the variable you're using. You're using `$marks` instead of `$mark`.

Your code:

```
@foreach($marks as $mark)
<option value="{{$marks->id}}">{{$marks->name_mark}}
```

Try this:

```
@foreach($marks as $mark)
<option value="{{$mark->id}}">{{$mark->name_mark}}
```

Another problem you're having, is that you're trying to retrieve a list for Marks but you're using a find method which brings the values by the key. This method suppose to bring just one record. Try the method where, with a different field. This gonna bring a list of records.

Comment: Thank you but I have this error message **"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object** ; I think it's in my SerieController here ? `public function edit($id)
    {
        $series = Serie::find($id);
        $marks = Mark::find($id);
        return view('admin.series.edit', compact('marks', 'series'));

    }`

Comment: try to debug what actually you are getting in your `$marks or $series ` variable like `dd($marks)`

Comment: @ Muhammad Shareyar: I get the same item everyimes. In the SerieController, I can have several models in fact?